# How to clean string coming from index

Tags: python, string

I am pulling values from a string but I am having a problem removing certain character.

```
Mandrake 9.2 (32 bit)
```

the index I pull from returns that, but I want to remove the (32 bit) and its length and location differ from line to line in file. I used [0:-8] but the problem was the variance in strings, so I tried this in my code

```
lines = re.sub(' [\d.]*', ' ', plines2)
```

but did not succeed.

more lines:

Redhat 7.3 (32bit)

```
Redhat 8.0 (32bit)
Mac OS X 10.4
Home Premium (32bit)
Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10
Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10
```

They vary, I want to be able to remove the 32 bit part as well as the version so that only the product name is there, it appears not on all lines as you see, some come with version and bit version but some only with one or the other.

Comment: It would help to provide examples of "other lines" so we're able to see what solution may be applicable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import re
ss = 'Mandrake 9.2 (32 bit)'
new_line = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)','',ss)  #'Mandrake 9.2 '
```

Note that this only works if you're guaranteed 1 set of matching parenthesis on a line...

With a slight variation, we can make it work with all the the things you have above:

```
new_line = re.sub(r'(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*)?(?:\(.*?\))?','',ss)
```

This will match version strings `number.number.number...` It will also match anything inside parenthesis (inclusive). Each match will be removed from the line.

Comment: I have a feeling something like `ss.split('(', 1)[0].rstrip()` would satisfy the OP, but as they haven't eloborated, it's difficult to tell. PS - maybe ".*?" ?

Comment: @JonClements -- Maybe I'm having a dense day but you lost me in the PS.  what did you mean by ".*?" ?

Comment: @JonClements -- right.  Thanks.  I use regex occasionally, but my skills are still not all that sharp.  I've updated (hopefully correctly).

Comment: this works great, but like you said it only works with guaranteed set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "Mandrake 9.2 (32 bit)"
>>> re.sub('\(\d.*\)','',line)
'Mandrake 9.2 '
```

if you want to remove the trailing and leading spaces

```
newstring.strip()
```

for example

```
>>> 'Mandrake 9.2 '.strip()
'Mandrake 9.2'
```

Comment: his works, but I am working with values from a list and so the .strip() attribute doesn't work on it.

Comment: stripped_list = [re.sub('\(\d.*\)','',e).strip() for e in raw_list]?